# Increase distance between two sections

Tags: html, css

```
section.profile{
    background: var(--black);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 3rem;

    margin-top: 60px;
}
section.profile .left{
flex: 2px;
display:flex;
align-items: center;
}
section.profile .right{
    flex:1;
}
section.profile .left h2{
    color: var(--fade);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight:600;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

This is the code and I'm attaching pictures for what I have and how I want it:

This is what I have right now
[image: This Is Mine What I Have Right Now]

And This is What I want it to look like
[image: See the Distance Between Them, How to do this?]

Thanks :)

Also here is the HTML Part
[image: PART 1]
[image: Part 2]

And here's the to code use (HTML): https://www.codepile.net/pile/2o9J4WZw
And Here's the code to use (CSS) : https://www.codepile.net/pile/2o9J4WZw

Comment: It would be very good for us to see the structure of your html.

Comment: I have added the HTML part

Comment: Can we copy code through images? Future tech maybe.

Comment: It's saying too much of code

Comment: @RohitSoni, no, this will not work. The code on the screen is bad practice for SO. Paste the code in text, pls.

Comment: @RohitSoni, if selector `.container` has a **flex** rule, then you can specify a `gap` rule. For example `.container { display: flex; gap: 30px; }`

Comment: i have added code to use link:

Answer (score 0):

add a padding left or margin left to  right section

```
.right{
   padding-left:25px
}
```

or

```
 .right{
  margin-left:25px
}
```

other wise you can use the bootstrap grid to divide into a two columns
reference:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

That what you want?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -40px; /* Do not forget this line of code */
}

.grid-item {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 40px; /* 80px between the sections */
}

.grow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-inner">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grow"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="grow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```